# Issue with the submit button in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

This is the code snippet of my form!! I'm facing issues with the disabling the submit button if the form is empty or partial filled button should be disabled, i need all the fields to filled!! can anyone suggest me what went wrong?

```html
    <form class="individual-form" method="post" [formGroup]="valueform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="input_tab" *ngIf="!showcontent">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input_text"><span>Name</span></div>
          <input type="Name" formControlName="Name" required class="signupForm_input " [(ngModel)]="name" id="login-name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
          <div *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors" class="errorMessage">
            <span *ngIf="name.hasError('required')">UserName is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="name.hasError('maxlength')">Only 10 characters allowed for UserName.</span>
            <span *ngIf="name.hasError('minlength')">Atleast 5 characters needed for UserName.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input_text"><span>Email</span></div>
          <input type="Email" formControlName="email" class="signupForm_input " [(ngModel)]="email" id="login-email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
          <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors" class="errorMessage">
            <span *ngIf="email.hasError('required')">Email is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="email.hasError('email')">Please provide valid email.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input_text"><span>Phone Number</span></div>
          <input type="Phone" formControlName="phone" class="signupForm_input" [(ngModel)]="phone" id="login-phone" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
          <div *ngIf="phone.touched && phone.errors" class="errorMessage">
            <span *ngIf="phone.hasError('required')">phone no is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="phone.hasError('phone')">Please provide valid phone no.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input_text"><span>Password</span></div>
          <input type="Password" formControlName="password" class="signupForm_input" [(ngModel)]="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <div *ngIf="password.touched && password.errors" class="errorMessage">
            <span *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">Password is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="password.hasError('maxlength')">Only 10 characters allowed for password.</span>
            <span *ngIf="password.hasError('minlength')">Atleast 5 characters needed for password.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input_text"><span>Confirm Password</span></div>
          <input type="confirm" formControlName="confirmpassword" class="signupForm_input" [(ngModel)]="cpassword" id="login-confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
          <div *ngIf="cpassword.touched && cpassword.errors" class="errorMessage">
            <span *ngIf="cpassword.hasError('required')">Confirm Password is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="cpassword.hasError('mustMatch')">Password Must Match.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

          <button [disabled]="valueform.invalid" class="submit" >SUBMIT</button><br>
        <button (click) ="gotoLogin()" class="login">LOGIN</button>
        <div class="terms">
          <span>By signing up you are agreeing our poilcy <a href="Privacy">Privacy </a>&<a href="terms">Terms.</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do as you are messing up everything.

your formcontrolName is "username" and you are checking validation like touched on "name". Similar for confirmpassword.

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

formcontrolName is already there then it is not needed to use [(ngModel)]="phone" in this simple case.Prefer to use either reactive or template not mix both.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642358/7562674

```
<form class="individual-form" method="post" [formGroup]="valueform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="input_tab" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_text"><span>Name</span></div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" required class="signupForm_input "  id="login-name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
            <div *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors" class="errorMessage">
              <span *ngIf="name.hasError('required')">UserName is required.</span>
              <span *ngIf="name.hasError('maxlength')">Only 10 characters allowed for UserName.</span>
              <span *ngIf="name.hasError('minlength')">Atleast 5 characters needed for UserName.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_text"><span>Email</span></div>
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="signupForm_input "  id="login-email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
            <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors" class="errorMessage">
              <span *ngIf="email.hasError('required')">Email is required.</span>
              <span *ngIf="email.hasError('email')">Please provide valid email.</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_text"><span>Phone Number</span></div>
            <input type="Phone" formControlName="phone" class="signupForm_input"  id="login-phone" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
            <div *ngIf="phone.touched && phone.errors" class="errorMessage">
              <span *ngIf="phone.hasError('required')">phone no is required.</span>
              <span *ngIf="phone.hasError('phone')">Please provide valid phone no.</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_text"><span>Password</span></div>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="signupForm_input"  id="login-password" placeholder="Password"><br>
            <div *ngIf="password.touched && password.errors" class="errorMessage">
              <span *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">Password is required.</span>
              <span *ngIf="password.hasError('maxlength')">Only 10 characters allowed for password.</span>
              <span *ngIf="password.hasError('minlength')">Atleast 5 characters needed for password.</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input_text"><span>Confirm Password</span></div>
            <input type="confirm" formControlName="cpassword" class="signupForm_input"  id="login-confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
            <div *ngIf="cpassword.touched && cpassword.errors" class="errorMessage">
              <span *ngIf="cpassword.hasError('required')">Confirm Password is required.</span>
              <span *ngIf="cpassword.hasError('mustMatch')">Password Must Match.</span>
            </div>
          </div>

            <button [disabled]="valueform.invalid" class="submit" >SUBMIT</button><br>
          <button (click) ="gotoLogin()" class="login">LOGIN</button>
          <div class="terms">
            <span>By signing up you are agreeing our poilcy <a href="Privacy">Privacy </a>&<a href="terms">Terms.</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

In Ts :-

```
   ngOnInit() {
        this.name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
        this.phone = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
        this.password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
        this.cpassword = new FormControl('',[Validators.required]);
        this.email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
        this.errorList = [];

        this.valueform = this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            'name': this.name,
            'email': this.email,
            'phone': this.phone,
            'password': this.password,
            'cpassword': this.cpassword,
          });
      }
```

Corrected mapping in ts and html. Let me know if still issue persist.

Comment: yea my bad!! mapped wrongly!! working fine now!! thanks

Comment: how can i display errors of the form only after clicking the submit button? currently my code show errors after every time I get into text field

Comment: It can be done in two ways:-
a.  Create a boolean flag isSubmitted=false and set after call to submit()
and in validation  add check for that flag.
b. In form [formGroup]="valueform" #ngForm="ngForm" and every validation add check ngForm.submitted

Comment: ive tried adding boolean but it isnt working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9jpk7e

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use formControlName and ngModel together as it is deprecated by Angular updates.

As you are using on submit, you should define the button type explicitly.

```
<button [disabled]="valueform.invalid" class="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

If you still face issues, it is to do with the form validators.

Comment: adding type didn't help either , not sure whats the problem with validators.i think everything is good is validators

Comment: Could you please then share the code from .ts file? Let's have a look to find the issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zmsajw  here is my ts file @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!valueform.valid" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `type="submit"` because if we not add type then by default it will be `type="button"`

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="valueform.invalid" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```